# Assistant Research Professor in a prestigious university or a tenure-track assistant professor in an R2 institute?

Tags: faculty-application, tenure-track, non-tenure

I'm debating over two positions to choose from. One is an Assistant Research Professor (fixed term, huge potentiality to be continued for at least another year or so) in a prestigious university. And, the other one is a tenure-track assistant professor in an R2 institute. Which one is better for the long-term? Do people treat assistant research professor position as a glorified postdoc? I don't like a lot of teaching and my offer from the R2 institute involves a lot of teaching. I aspire to move to a BIG research institute in the future. So, what would you advice?

Comment: You need to decide this for yourself based on your desires.  I do not see how strangers with different goals and no detailed knowledge of the universities can help you.

Comment: Assistant Research Professor sounds *exactly* like a postdoc to me.  What are its duties?  Do they seem different in any way from a postdoc?  Also, what field is this?